# how to start a instance of dbmonitor mysqlmonitor in a console application

Tags: devart, dotconnect

This is probably simple, but I have not found how to do it.

Needing to monitor my C# console application in vs 2015.

The help file for dbMonitor states:
"You can do it by dropping MySqlMonitor on form from toolbox or by creating it manually in code."

But I cannot find out *how* to create it manually in code.

I am using the PostgreSQL dot connect.

When I run dbMonitor it does not see my processes.

--Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I missed it:

`PgSqlMonitor pgMonitor = new PgSqlMonitor();
            pgMonitor.IsActive = true;`

Comment: Side note: This feature is not available to Express Edition user: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/editions.html